# VB.NET Share Code / Centralize Code

Tags: sql, wpf, vb.net

I have an application that will be running on several desktop computers simultaneously (It will stay open 24/7). At midnight, Data will be copied from one table to another. Since my program will be open on several different machines, it will attempt to make this transaction multiple times which could cause loss of data. How do I centralize my code where this event will occur only one time? Any help will be greatly appreciated. I have several ideas as to how I could do this by scheduling a task on windows using a small app I made; however, my desire is to include the code to "copy the tables" in the application itself. Thanks.

Comment: What about having your app loading a file with the specific updates while a service on the server sequentially loads this data in the appropriate table?

Comment: This is currently what I am most likely to do. We currently have a service that runs on our server that powers our other applications. I just would like to not have to use a separate service and include the code within the application itself,.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you are doing without a service directing your tasks you could still create a data schema that does.  E.g. Create table(s) to track when tasks are started and stopped and run a query to see if it is in process prior to starting the task if it is then skip the task and move onto the next one.  If you use a service you still need some tracking mechanism and a table would still be handy but design it write and your application can go straight to the central data repository and figure out what is up on its own.